# MYSQL restrict deletion of child record if parent is not null

Tags: mysql

I have orphan-able child records ( ON DELETE SET NULL ) so that a parent record can be deleted without deleting the children. Deleting the parent is permissible.

However, if the child's parent column is NOT NULL, deleting the child record is not permissible.

I want to restrict delete of child records with parents, but not allow deletion child records that have parents. Also permit deletion of parents without deleting the child records.

Is there a way to do this with referential actions only or do I need to use  triggers as well?

Comment: I'm not aware of any built-in option that prevents deletions based on data, other than foreign keys (which are of no use here). Triggers would be an option if that's required to be server-side, otherwise go for a client-side solution.

Comment: No way to force this via foreign keys, you need to use triggers.